# the program can't start because xinput1_3.dll is missing from your computer

Tags: windows-8.1, directx

I'm trying to run `Elite Dangerous Launcher`, yet I keep getting following error:

```
the program can't start because xinput1_3.dll is missing from your computer
```

According to: [How to install the latest version of DirectX](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/179113), `DirectX` is ***ALREADY*** installed on my Windows 8.1 system.

Why am I getting this error then? How do I actually solve this?

Comment: Did you install the latest [DirectX update](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35)?

Comment: @DanielB as I mentioned in my question earlier, I'm running Windows 8.1 that _ALREADY_ comes with `DirectX` 11 and DirectX End-User Runtime 9.0c isn't even compatible with Windows 8.1.

Comment: Actually... It is...

Comment: You have DX11 capatible hardware correct?

Comment: @Ramhound so what you're saying is even though Microsoft did _NOT_ specified under "System Requirements" Windows 8 _AND_ another article says Windows 8.1 comes with latest Direct X 11.2, I should still go ahead and install DirectX 9.0c?? I'm using `VirtualBox` and Windows 8.1 is my guest OS, my host is `MacBook Pro (Retina, 15-inch, Early 2013)`.

Comment: There are many versions of the DirectX API. Windows does not ship with all versions. So yes, do install.

Comment: http://www.microsoft.com/en-ca/download/details.aspx?id=8109

Comment: Alright.  We have identified the problem more then likely.  I am going to take a wild guess and say the reason the DirectX 11 game isn't working is because your using a VirtualBox which display drivers are not compatible with it.  **Yes** Direct X 9 and Direct X 11 are entirely separate frameworks, a program can be targeted to one or both, all depends on the programmer.

Comment: This isn’t about DirectX 11 at all. XInput has been around since DirectX 9, and that’s what needs to be updated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Install [DirectX End-User Runtime Web Installer](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35&44F86079-8679-400C-BFF2-9CA5F2BCBDFC=1)

Comment: Please give more details. What is "this"? How does it solve the problem?

Comment: The above link is now a prompt to download Windows 10.  Not sure the DX Web Installer is available from MS any longer.

Comment: Just for adding alternative link because the link given by Jason is not available anymore.
Download from here: [http://download.microsoft.com/download/8/4/A/84A35BF1-DAFE-4AE8-82AF-AD2AE20B6B14/directx_Jun2010_redist.exe](http://download.microsoft.com/download/8/4/A/84A35BF1-DAFE-4AE8-82AF-AD2AE20B6B14/directx_Jun2010_redist.exe)

Answer (score 1):

That file is a part of the DirectX 9 runtime, which is NOT bundled with Windows 8.1. You can install a DirectX compatibility package from here: [DirectX End-User Runtimes (June 2010)](https://www.microsoft.com/en-ca/download/details.aspx?id=8109).

Installing this bundle should solve your problem with `xinput1_3.dll` as well as anything related to `d3dx11_43.dll`, `d3dx10_43.dll`, `D3DX9_43.dll`, `XAudio2_7.dll` and others.

Answer (score -2):

Can you still find xinput1_3.dll on the PC? Get a new copy of it to replace the old one may help solve the problem. The methods mentioned in the following posts may be working:

http://pcsupport.about.com/od/findbyerrormessage/a/xinput1_3-dll-not-found-missing-error.htm
http://www.bestpcsavior.com/how-can-you-fix-xinput1_3-dll-missing-errors/

Good luck.

Comment: Can we not advertise that website?